# Typescript import code from outside root, compiles to folder

Tags: typescript

I have a folder structure that looks like this

```
-- gcf 
   - index.ts
-- cloud 
   -- cloud
      - errorHandler.ts
```

I specify outDir to be lib which means I want to end up with a folder structure like this after compile

```
  --lib
    --cloud
        --cloud
          -errorHandler.js
    -index.js
```

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@cloud/*": ["../cloud/cloud/*"]
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },

  "lib": ["es2015"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Tried Setting RootDir but makes no difference.

Currently this compiles my index.js into a folder gcf,

So the current compiled code looks like this:

```
--lib
  -- cloud
  -- gcf/index.js
```

index.js should be directly in the lib folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect the gcf directory to be dealt with differently than the cloud directory.

Comment: If I remove the import to cloud, it compiles to lib/index.js
So why would the import from the outside directory all of a sudden put the root files in a folder?

Comment: Because your import is presumably `from "../cloud/cloud/errorHandler"`

Comment: import looks like this 
  import { errorHandler } from '@cloud/errorHandler';
I specify paths in the tsconfig so I don't need ../../

I just don't get how that would affect where the index.js file is compiled

Comment: Ah, I see, but that just gets the compiler to rewrite `@cloud` to `../cloud/cloud`.

Comment: Yes pretty much makes no difference. Just makes the path look fancy,  But still not solving the problem.